# move text to the right of the button upon file select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this jsfiddle. I was able to move the box to the left. However, when I click on the Choose File button and select an image, the file name writes over Choose File button. It is supposed to write over the white space next to Choose File button.

This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5nq8Le7p/12/

```
#val {
width: 300px;
height:25px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
font-size:13px;
line-height: 25px;
text-indent: 10px;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Can someone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to only move the element when a file is selected. Simply set `left: 90px` on `#val` in the CSS

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

$("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #ededed;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

input[type='file'] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0
}

#val {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 90px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: purple;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms all;
  -moz-transition: 500ms all;
  transition: 500ms all;
}

#button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id='button'>Choose File</span>
  <input type='file'> <span id='val'></span>
</div>
```